# Cannnot resolve method addPaintListener

Tags: java, canvas, methods, resolve

I'm trying to draw on the canvas by adding addPaintListeners function in the Main file as follows, but I'm getting an error 'cannot resolve method 'addPaintListener(eos.listeners.PaintListener)

Canvas that uses our PaintListener. This canvas is the same code as the Official Java.AWT.Canvas class.

We have add a buffer to the canvas so we can draw on and we have added a PaintListener property:

added a function to addPaintListeners to  canvas

```
import    package eos;

import eos.listeners.PaintListener;
import eos.utility.Util;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class Main {
private static JLabel splash = new JLabel(Util.loadIcon("http://www.runescape.com/img/game/splash.gif"));

private static void displayFrame(String world, int width, int height) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Eos");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    if (splash != null) {
        frame.add(splash);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    centerFrame(frame);

    ClientApplet applet = new ClientApplet(world, width, height);
    frame.add(applet);
    applet.start();
    if (splash != null) {
        frame.remove(splash);
    }
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.pack();

    centerFrame(frame);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            applet.stop();
            frame.dispose();
            super.windowClosed(e);
        }
    });
}


private static void centerFrame(JFrame frame) {
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int cX = (toolkit.getScreenSize().width / 2) - (frame.getWidth() / 2);
    int cY = (toolkit.getScreenSize().height / 2) - (frame.getHeight() / 2);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
    frame.setLocation(cX, cY);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
}

public static void notifyCanvasReady(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.addPaintListener((PaintListener) g -> {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("HELLO WORLD", 50, 50);




    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayFrame("http://runescape.com", 800, 600);
}
}
```

```
package java.awt;

import eos.Main;
import eos.listeners.PaintListener;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleContext;
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleRole;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.peer.CanvasPeer;


public class Canvas extends Component implements Accessible {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2284879212465893870L;
private static int nameCounter = 0;
private static final String base = "canvas";

private BufferedImage debugImage;
private transient PaintListener paintListener;

public Canvas() {
    Main.notifyCanvasReady(this);
}

public Canvas(GraphicsConfiguration config) {
    this();
    setGraphicsConfiguration(config);
}

public void addPaintListener(PaintListener listener) {
    paintListener = (PaintListener)AWTEventMulticaster.addInternal(paintListener, listener);
}

@Override
public Graphics getGraphics() {
    if (debugImage == null || debugImage.getWidth() != getWidth() || debugImage.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
        debugImage = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    Graphics g = debugImage.getGraphics();

    if (paintListener != null) {
        paintListener.onPaint(g);
    }

    super.getGraphics().drawImage(debugImage, 0, 0, null);

    return g;
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
}

@Override
void setGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
    synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
        CanvasPeer peer = (CanvasPeer)getPeer();
        if (peer != null) {
            gc = peer.getAppropriateGraphicsConfiguration(gc);
        }
        super.setGraphicsConfiguration(gc);
    }
}

@Override
String constructComponentName() {
    synchronized (Canvas.class) {
        return base + nameCounter++;
    }
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
        if (peer == null)
            peer = getToolkit().createCanvas(this);
        super.addNotify();
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    paint(g);
}

@Override
boolean postsOldMouseEvents() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void createBufferStrategy(int numBuffers) {
    super.createBufferStrategy(numBuffers);
}

@Override
public void createBufferStrategy(int numBuffers, BufferCapabilities caps) throws AWTException {
    super.createBufferStrategy(numBuffers, caps);
}

@Override
public BufferStrategy getBufferStrategy() {
    return super.getBufferStrategy();
}

@Override
public AccessibleContext getAccessibleContext() {
    if (accessibleContext == null) {
        accessibleContext = new AccessibleAWTCanvas();
    }
    return accessibleContext;
}

protected class AccessibleAWTCanvas extends AccessibleAWTComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6325592262103146699L;

    @Override
    public AccessibleRole getAccessibleRole() {
        return AccessibleRole.CANVAS;
    }
}
}
```

```
 package eos.listeners;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.EventListener;




public interface PaintListener extends EventListener {
public void onPaint(Graphics g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the way you are calling this method in Main. Try this approach:

```
public static void notifyCanvasReady(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPaint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("HELLO WORLD", 50, 50);            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi I replaced the original code with yours and I got this error.                   
    'Error:(67, 15) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method addPaintListener(<anonymous 
    eos.listeners.PaintListener>)
    location: variable canvas of type java.awt.Canvas'

Comment: Then maybe there is a problem with import organization and order.